# Android - pass several parameters with putExtras between two activities

Tags: android

Pass brush size and brush shape between `MainActivity` and `ChangeBrush`.

Main:

```
static final int ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SIZE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
static final int ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SHAPE_REQUEST_CODE = 3;

public void onClickBrush(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeBrush.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SIZE_REQUEST_CODE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SHAPE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

ChangeBrush:

```
 public void onClickChangeBrushSize(View view) {
    String size = view.getTag().toString().;

    // return the brush size to main activity
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("size", size);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}

public void onClickChangeBrushShape(View view) {
    String shape = view.getTag().toString();

    // return the brush shape to main activity
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("shape", shape);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```

`SelectBrush` activity layout:

[image]

When user click the `size` button and `shape` button in `ChangeBrush` activity, they could pass `size` and `shape` to `MainActivity`. In `MainActivity`, I use `onActivityResult` to set the brush size and shape.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        String color = bundle.getString("color");
        String size = bundle.getString("size");
        String shape = bundle.getString("shape");

        switch(requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_COLOR_REQUEST_CODE:
                fingerPainterView.setColour(Color.parseColor(color)); // set new color value

            case ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SIZE_REQUEST_CODE:
                Log.d("FingerPainter", "Main activity change brush size to " + size);

            case ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SHAPE_REQUEST_CODE:
                Log.d("FingerPainter", "Main activity change brush shape to " + shape);
        }

    } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.d("FingerPainter", "MainActivity canceled");

    }
}
```

This will log the return value:

```
D/FingerPainter: Main activity change brush shape to null
D/FingerPainter: Main activity change brush size to null
D/FingerPainter: Main activity change brush shape to SQUARE
```

It seems the return value could correspond to the right intent. I don't know why it log the shape information twice. Is there anything wrong with  `finish()`? I want the user select both size and shape, and then return to the main activity.

If the method is wrong, what should I do to pass these two values?

Comment: What buttons do you have mapped to `onClickBrush`? All of them? You should divide the Size and Shape buttons into two separate intents.

Comment: @cricket_007 `onClickBrush` starts the `ChangeBrush` activity. In `ChangeBrush` activity, I divide size and shape into two intents (methods).

Comment: It looks like `onClickBrush` starts `ChangeBrush` twice at the moment.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, because I have to receive two results from `ChangeBrush`. Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I see:

**1:** You are calling `startActivityForResult` twice. You can pass extras using `intent.putExtra(...)`.

**2:** You don't have a `break` in your `switch` statement:

```
switch(requestCode) {
    case ACTIVITY_COLOR_REQUEST_CODE:
        fingerPainterView.setColour(Color.parseColor(color)); // set new color value
    break;
    case ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SIZE_REQUEST_CODE:
        Log.d("FingerPainter", "Main activity change brush size to " + size);
    break;
    case ACTIVITY_BRUSH_SHAPE_REQUEST_CODE:
        Log.d("FingerPainter", "Main activity change brush shape to " + shape);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I add the `break` just now, and it will only return one shape and one size. It works when I select shape first and then select size. It will return the right value to main. But if I select size first, then select shape. Both of them will return  `null` to main.

Comment: What's the difference between using `startActivityForResult` and `intent.putExtra(...)`? Do you mean `intent.putExtra(size, value)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update multiple things from a single Intent, I think you need to save off the current data that already exists in the Activity.

```
public void onClickBrush(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeBrush.class);
    // intent.putExtra("shape", currentShape); // for example 

    // then, only start one Activity, with a generic request code, not one Activity twice with two codes
```

In other words, you start one Activity capable of changing all the data (even though you only update a single value at a time). So, save the current values when you start the next Activity, pass those back as unchanged while you update the new values. Then you shouldn't get null values.

For example, for the shape button.

```
public void onClickChangeBrushShape(View view) {
    String shape = view.getTag().toString();

    // return the brush shape to main activity
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("shape", shape); // Set the new shape

    bundle.putString("color", color); // I assume you've saved this
    bundle.putString("size", size);  // and this...

    // You could put string extras into the intent directly, but whatever
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```

---

Another option is using SharedPreferences to store all the values and forget about Intents and Bundles.

Comment: Which part? I was giving an example that you are dealing with many overlapping methods and variables, and I said SharedPreferences would be better.

Comment: I think it only requires to send back the value, then set the shape and size in main, so SharedPreferences is not useful. Color is in another activity.

Comment: Please explain why you prefer Intents over SharedPreferences. It's much more suited to the task you ask trying

Comment: Actually, this coursework doesn't contain the SharePreferences.... it is in the next assignment, so I preder Intent...